# Ruby TCPSocket: Find out how much data is available

Tags: ruby, sockets, nonblocking, tcpsocket

Is there a way to find out how many bytes of data is available on an TCPSocket in Ruby? I.e. how many bytes can be ready without blocking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard library `io/wait` might be useful here.  Requiring it gives stream-based I/O (sockets and pipes) some new methods, among which is `ready?`.  According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/io/wait/rdoc/index.html), ready? returns non-nil if there are bytes available without blocking.  It just so happens that the non-nil value it returns it the number of bytes that are available *in MRI*.

Here's an example which creates a dumb little socket server, and then connects to it with a client.  The server just sends "foo" and then closes the connection.  The client waits a little bit to give the server time to send, and then prints how many bytes are available for reading.  The interesting stuff for you is in the client:

```
require 'socket'
require 'io/wait'

# Server

server_socket = TCPServer.new('localhost', 0)
port = server_socket.addr[1]
Thread.new do
  session = server_socket.accept
  sleep 0.5
  session.puts "foo"
  session.close
end

# Client

client_socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', port)
puts client_socket.ready?    # => nil
sleep 1
puts client_socket.ready?    # => 4
```

Don't use that server code in anything real.  It's deliberately short in order to keep the example simple.

Note: According to the Pickaxe book, io/wait is only available if "FIONREAD feature in ioctl(2)", which it is in Linux.  I don't know about Windows & others.

Comment: Do you know by any chance if it is available for JRuby?

Comment: @panzi, I don't know JRuby, so I don't know.  This page suggests that the functionality may be available but using different classes than MRI:http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/util/io/CRLFStreamWrapper.html (scroll down to `ready?`).

Comment: I tried it under JRuby. The method is there but it does only return `1` instead of the real amount if something can be read. Well, I can implement it without this but it would have been more efficient.

Comment: @panzi, I wondered if `ready?` returning a count was a quirk of MRI.  Now you've confirmed that it is.  I apologize for leading you down a false trail.

Comment: I am using the SSLSocket. The function .ready? does not seem to exist there. Is there any other feature I can use on the SSLSocket?

Comment: @MarekKüthe Unfortunately I do not know.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller Thank you for your edit, especially to the outdated word I used.  It's a small edit but a big improvement.